# Getting ID after insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I use this stored procedure to make insert and return the id of inserted row

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addObjective]
(
            @Name nvarchar(250)
           ,@ObjectiveGroupId int
           ,@CreatorId int
           ,@LanguageId int
           ,@isFinal bit
)
as 
insert into Objective values
(
            @Name
           ,@ObjectiveGroupId
           ,@CreatorId
           ,GETDATE()
           ,@LanguageId
           ,@isFinal
)

    select scope_identity() as Id;
```

But how to read the returned id using `vb.net` code

using this commands return `-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using the return value from a call to `.ExecuteNonQuery()` in your VB.NET code (which you're not showing us...... so I can only guess).

That's the wrong value to read - that value would return the number of rows that were affected by your last SQL statement (e.g. by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`).

Since your stored procedure **IS** returning a value - the newly inserted `ID` - and it's returning a single row, single column value (just the `ID`, nothing else), you need to read that value - e.g. by calling `.ExecuteScalar()` instead:

```
Dim newID As Integer = CInt(yourInsertCmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (tablename) order by (id) DESC
for x = 0 to (tablename).rows.count - 1
savedid = (tablename).rows(x).item("id").tostring
next
```