# Insert into two tables with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm having a problem on adding data in my database. I have two tables; the first one is tblemployee_information and the other one is tblemployee_account. My problem is, how can I save the employee_id in tblemployee_account as a foreign key? It's working but the employee id in tblemployee_account is NULL, after I add a data.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE tblemployee_information (
    employee_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    employee_first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_middle_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_contact varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_address varchar(200) NOT NULL  
);

--Table Structure for Employees Account
CREATE TABLE tblemployee_account (
    employee_account_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    employee_password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    employee_id int REFERENCES tblemployee_information(employee_id)
);
```

**Codes for Adding Data**

```
Public Sub addEmployee()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tblemployee_information(employee_first_name, employee_middle_name, employee_last_name, employee_contact, employee_address) VALUES (@employee_first_name, @employee_middle_name, @employee_last_name, @employee_contact, @employee_address)"
            command1 = New SqlCommand
            With command1
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = insert_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_first_name", Register.txtFirstName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_middle_name", Register.txtMiddleName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_last_name", Register.txtLastName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_contact", Register.txtContact.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_address", Register.txtAddress.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            'This command will insert the email, username & password from another table
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tblemployee_account(employee_email, employee_username, employee_password) VALUES (@employee_email, @employee_username, @employee_password)"
            command2 = New SqlCommand
            With command2
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = insert_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_email", Register.txtEmail.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_username", Register.txtUsername.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_password", Register.txtPassword.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command1.Dispose()
            command2.Dispose()
            MsgBox("Data Added Successfully.")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You still need to insert the `employee_id` into the `tblemployee_account` table. Return the `employee_id` after you insert it into the `tblemployee_information`.

Comment: How? The employee_id is auto-increment, btw.

Comment: `Scope_Identity()` or turn the insert into a stored proc, then return the `employee_id` to code.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I don't know on how to use scope_identity, tbh.

Comment: You should look at the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052324/getting-id-after-insert-in-sql-server) and create a separate stored procedure for employee information and account. You need to verify that the information insert was successful.

Comment: I would suggest moving all of this code out of your application and create a stored procedure that can do both inserts inside a single transaction. Way simpler for your code, better separation in your code and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If I were building I would do both inserts inside a stored procedure. Here is what you procedure would look like.

But there is a MAJOR problem here. You are storing passwords in plain text. This is an absolutely horrible way to handle passwords. They need to be salted and hashed at all times. That is really outside the scope of your question but it would be an incomplete response if I don't mention and stress how big of a problem this is. YOU MUST fix this!!!

```
create procedure Employee_Inserts
(
    @employee_first_name varchar(100),
    @employee_middle_name varchar(100),
    @employee_last_name varchar(100),
    @employee_contact varchar(100),
    @employee_address varchar(200), 
    @employee_email varchar(100),
    @employee_username varchar(50),
    @employee_password varchar(50)
) as begin

    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO tblemployee_information
    (
        employee_first_name
        , employee_middle_name
        , employee_last_name
        , employee_contact
        , employee_address
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
        @employee_first_name
        , @employee_middle_name
        , @employee_last_name
        , @employee_contact
        , @employee_address
    )

    INSERT INTO tblemployee_account
    (
        employee_account_id
        , employee_email
        , employee_username
        , employee_password
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        , @employee_email
        , @employee_username
        , @employee_password
    )
end
```